# New android modal in 13?

Tags: java, android

[image]So this app called xrecorder shows this modal or popup when a user is trying to request the draw over apps permission, at first I thought they must be using some grandfathered way of doing it but they just updated their app. I am talking about the top part of the image with the dark but opaque background. I always thought that you cant put any popups on the android settings app.

Are they using bubbles in android 13?

I would appreciate if anyone knew how this was being done.

All other ways I know of doing this get blocked by window permissions.

Comment: How many devices have you tested it on? Do they use stock android?

Comment: @Pawel yes stock standard devices, one of my team members tried it on an older device with android 10 and he said it didn't show up.  Which leads me to think it's and Android 13 thing but can't be sure.

Comment: anyone have any ideas on this?